# how to load from file to my App like blender file

Tags: c#, opengl

how to use the parse class in this code

```
private void openModelToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    Stream myStream = null;
    OpenFileDialog theDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    theDialog.Title = "Open Text File";
    theDialog.Filter = "TXT files|*.txt";
    theDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";

    if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((myStream = theDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                using (myStream)
                {
                    // Insert code to read the stream here.
                    string FileString = theDialog.FileName;
                    string FileText = File.ReadAllText(FileString);
                    glcontrol_1.Text = FileText;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question. It is not clear what you are asking. Check how to ask questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you have a question here?

Answer (score 0):

> how to use the parse class in this code

The code snippet you posted there is no parser. All it does is showing a "Open File Dialog" and that's it. Parsing a file involved reading and then *interpreting* its contents. The code you have just reads a file and that's it. Also Blender files are very hard to interpret. Not impossible, but in general it's easier to export from Blender into an easy to process format and then read that with a ready to use library like Assimp.